# HAProxy redirect one URL into another

Tags: haproxy

I’m quite new to HAProxy and have what I believe to be a simple use-case:
I want to redirect requests made into my KVM host --> URL of the guest VMs. 
In my case the redirects are for several VMs that run HTTPS content.

Example:
-- HAProxy is running on the KVM host (10.10.10.5 - ansout.mine.local)
-- HTTPS guest VM running on KVM (172.10.10.5 - ans.lab.local)

How can I make a request from a client (on the KVM network) to ‘http://ansout.mine.local’ and redirect it into, 'https://ans.lab.local'

It would seem I need to use the ‘http-request redirect’ function in HAProxy but I still can’t wrap my head around it.
Could anyone one kindly provide some pointers on how to achieve the example above?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the client then should connect directly to ans.lab.local.

```
listen http-in
  bind :80

  log stdout format raw daemon
  mode http
  option httplog

  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if HTTP

  timeout client   5s
  timeout connect 30s
  timeout server  30s

  http-request redirect code 301 location https://ans.lab.local if { hdr(host) -i ansout.mine.local }
```

If you have several hosts which you want to redirect please take a look into [HAProxy Maps](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-maps/).